# Python: csv.writerow() splitting a key character by character?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Given:

```
import csv
def writeToCsv(rows):
    with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Name', '#Reviews', 'Address', 'Phone']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

When I attempt:

```
row = {
    'Name': self.validEntries.keys()[0],
    '#Reviews': self.validEntries.values()[0],
    'Address': (nap[0] + ', ' + nap[1]),
    'Phone': nap[2]
}
writeToCsv(row)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: dict contains field not in fieldnames: 'P', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'e'
```

Why is `writerow` splitting this field (I imagine it will do the same for each field) character by character?

Comment: You should be either passing a dicts to writer.writerows or use a csv.writer, you are passing strings as you iterate over the keys

Comment: On a side note, you should open the file in _binary_ mode, as recommended in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yep, the function was expecting a bunch of rows, but only getting a single one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the `dictionary` into the `writer.writerow` , instead of passing each `key` into the write rows seperately.

Also, if you want to write multiple rows (meaning list of multiple dictionaries) into the csv together, you can use - `writer.writerows(rows)` passing the list of diciontaries into it.

Example -

```
import csv
with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Name', '#Reviews', 'Address', 'Phone']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    row = {'Name':'Blah','#Reviews':'Blah','Address':'Blah','Phone':'Blah'}
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(row)
    rows = [{'Name':'Blah2','#Reviews':'Blah2','Address':'Blah2','Phone':'Blah2'},{'Name':'Blah1','#Reviews':'Blah1','Address':'Blah1','Phone':'Blah1'}]
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

After this the `results.csv` looks like -

```
Name,#Reviews,Address,Phone
Blah,Blah,Blah,Blah
Blah2,Blah2,Blah2,Blah2
Blah1,Blah1,Blah1,Blah1
```

In your case you need to use `writer.writerow(rows)` without looping through the rows.

Or you can also send in a list of rows as `writeToCsv([row])` , but then still you do not need to iterate over the rows, you should use `writer.writerows()` to write the rows into the dictionary. (notice the extra `s`)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the code to:

```
row = {'Name': self.validEntries.keys()[0], '#Reviews' : self.validEntries.values()[0], 'Address' : (nap[0] + ', ' + nap[1]), 'Phone': nap[2]}
writeToCsv([row])
```

Your writeToCsv expecting a list not a dict.